# Clustering similar strings based on another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, cluster-analysis

I have a large data frame that shows the distance between strings and their counts.

For example, in row 1, you see the distance between ***apple*** and ***pple*** as well as the times that I have counted ***apple (counts_col1= 100)*** and the times I ve counted ***pple (counts_col2=2)***.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(col1 = c("apple","apple","pple", "banana", "banana","bananna"),
                 col2 = c("pple","app","app", "bananna", "banan", "banan"), 
             distance = c(1,2,3,1,1,2),
          counts_col1 = c(100,100,2,200,200,2),
          counts_col2 = c(2,50,50,2,20,20))
df    
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   col1    col2    distance counts_col1 counts_col2
#>   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 apple   pple           1         100           2
#> 2 apple   app            2         100          50
#> 3 pple    app            3           2          50
#> 4 banana  bananna        1         200           2
#> 5 banana  banan          1         200          20
#> 6 bananna banan          2           2          20
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Now I want to cluster the apples and the bananas based on the string that has the maximum number of counts, which is the apple (100) and the banana (200).
I want my data to look somehow like this

```
cluster   elements  sum_counts
 apple      apple    152
  NA        pple      NA
  NA         app      NA
 banana     banana   222
  NA       bananna    NA
  NA         banan    NA
```

**The format of the output does not have to be like this. I am really struggling to break down this problem and cluster the groups.
Any help or comment are really appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using random walk clustering from `igraph`:

```
count_df <- data.table::melt(
  data.table::as.data.table(df), 
  measure = list(c("col1", "col2"), c("counts_col1", "counts_col2")),
  value.name = c("col", "counts")
) %>%
  select(col, counts) %>%
  unique()

df %>%
  igraph::graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  igraph::walktrap.community(weights = igraph::E(.)$distance) %>%
  # igraph::components() %>%
  igraph::membership() %>%
  split(names(.), .) %>%
  map_dfr(
    ~tibble(col = .x) %>% 
      semi_join(count_df, ., by = "col") %>% 
      arrange(desc(counts)) %>%
      summarise(cluster = first(col), elements = list(col), sum_count = sum(counts))
  )

  cluster               elements sum_count
1   apple       apple, app, pple       152
2  banana banana, banan, bananna       222
```

This works on this toy example, but I think your example is to simple and probably does not reflect your main problem. Or it might be even easier if you are interested in finding connected components (if two words are connected they are in same cluster). Then you would need to replace `walktrap.community` with `components`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, where I initially add a group identifier for the sets (I presume you have this in your actual set), and then after making a longer type dataset, I group by this `id`, and identifier the "word" that has the largest value. I then use an inner join between the initial df and this resulting set of key rows that have the largest_value word, summarize, and rename. I push all the variants into a list column.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

df %>% inner_join(
   rbind(
    df %>% select(id,distance,col=col1, counts=counts_col1),
    df %>% select(id,distance,col=col2, counts=counts_col2)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice_max(counts) %>% 
  distinct(col), 
  by=c("col1"="col")
) %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  summarize(variants = list(c(col1, cur_group()$col1)),
            total = min(counts_col1) + sum(counts_col2)) %>% 
  rename_all(~c("cluster", "elements", "sum_counts"))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  cluster elements  sum_counts
  <chr>   <list>         <dbl>
1 apple   <chr [3]>        152
2 banana  <chr [3]>        222
```

A similar approach in data.table (also depends on having that `id` column)

```
setDT(df)
df[rbind(
  df[,.(id,col=col1,counts=counts_col1)],
  df[,.(id,col=col2,counts=counts_col2)]
)[order(-counts),.SD[1], by=id],on=.(col1=col)][
  ,  .(elements=list(c(col2,.BY$cluster)),
       sum_counts = min(counts_col1) + sum(counts_col2)),
  by=.(cluster=col1)]


   cluster             elements sum_counts
    <char>               <list>      <num>
1:  banana bananna,banan,banana        222
2:   apple       pple,app,apple        152
```

Comment: Dear @langtang, this is a great answer and I have upvoted it of course. I love it. Unfortunately i do not have the id column and I need to find a way to create it. 
The data i ve post it is the output of 30000*30000 matrix and here are only the elements that have distance below 4

Comment: hmm, then how do you know that apple is different from banana?

Comment: good question! the matrix is huge and the algorithm in order to save space and memory writes down only the elements that have distance below 4 (or whatever threshold I set). apple and banana have distance greater than 4 and for this they are not written